# Standard errors of parameters in hyperparameter tuning

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, hyperparameter, profile-likelihood

I have a model with the parameters  $\textbf{θ} = (\textbf{φ}, ψ)$, which I trying to estimate. There is an out-of-the-box solution for ML estimating $\textbf{φ}$ if $ψ$ is fixed. If I treat $ψ$ as hyperparameter, I can obtain it by brute force, f.e. using grid search (get profile likelihood for every $ψ$ from the greed). It looks easy.
The problem is how to obtain standard errors not only for hyperparameter, but also for each parameter from $\textbf{φ}$. As I understand, confidence intervals from the output of out-of-the-box function for best $ψ$ are not confidence interval for general model where $ψ$ is variable (see http://www.gllamm.org/Jeon&RabeHesketh_JEBS_2012.p).
I know there are some packages R which enable hyperparameter tuning for the external (e.g. user) function but they don’t estimate SE of model’s parameters (that is $\textbf{φ}$). I have found a few solutions for the particular cases (the link above), but not for the general one.
My question:

1. What hampers to receive the estimation SE through bootstrap:
   (1) Generate $N$ samples from my data.
   (2) Receive with grid search for each
   sample *i* - $ψ_i$, providing maximum profile likelihood. 
   (3) For each $ψ_i$ -
   receive $\textbf{φ}_i (ψ_i)$. 
   (4) Having $N$ estimations $\textbf{φ}$ and $ψ$ estimate SE. 
   Are
   there some problems with this solution except for the computational
   resources?
2. Is there any helpful literature on this problem or ready
   solutions in R?